# request: linguistics self-study exercises (worksheets or exercises)

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for linguistics exercises to do over the summer. These can be from websites providing worksheets, or recommendations of textbooks which contain such exercises or worksheets, or recommendations of self-study tips and techniques.

**Background**
I have just finished my second year of linguistics and philosophy at university, and I want to get more practice doing these exercises to help me decide whether I want to commit to linguistics as a major for my 3rd and 4th years.

Some linguistics popularisers, such as [Martin Hilpert](https://youtu.be/oLbpu-UHzI4?t=392), or some [commenters around here](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12371/any-solid-textbook-recommendations-to-begin-studying-linguistics), have noted that unlike in other humanities subjects, when you study linguistics, you do not just write essays, and instead, you actually learn to do linguistic analyses of data-sets. For whatever reason, I have had very little experience doing this in my degree: most of my courses have been assessed through essay-writing. While I like writing essays, I want to get more experience doing linguistic analysis of data-sets before committing to linguistics as a major (potentially to study at postgrad level).

**Specification**
The type of exercise I am looking for, as described in the [Linguistics Stack Exchange discussion I linked above](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/12371/any-solid-textbook-recommendations-to-begin-studying-linguistics) involves a data-set (either provided on the worksheet or collected by me), which I must then analyse by looking for relevant theories to explain the data, and applying one that looks to fit well.

While that is the primary type of exercise I am looking for, I will also welcome any other type of self-study resource if you think I might find it useful. The areas of linguistics I am most interested in are: semantics, pragmatics, metaphor, cognitive linguistics, the mental lexicon, first language acquisition, language evolution, sociolinguistics, and discourse analysis. However, I welcome exercises relating to other areas of linguistics too.

Comment: For historical linguistics, I recommend Blust 2018 *101 Problems and Solutions in Historical Linguistics: A Workbook* https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/101-problems-and-solutions-historical-linguistics

Comment: My Introduction to Linguistic Analysis coursepacks are mostly composed of problems and handouts. They're scans and they're free. [Part 1](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/210CourspackPart1.pdf) covers morphology, phonetics, and phonology; [Part 2](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/210CourspackPart2.pdf) covers syntax, semantics, and selected short subjects. [Class syllabus here](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/210.html).